# Angular Material Chips to be displayed under the input box

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I am using Angular Material to create chips entered in the input field. So, the current default behaviour as given in documentation [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) is to display chips inside the input box. I don't want to show those chips inside my input field what I wanna do is when user enters anything, the chip should be created under the input field(not inside the input field). You can just help me with any example link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>If you look at the [Angular Material Chip](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input) example you can pull the input out of `mat-form-field`</strike>

**Update:** If you reorder the input element in the [example from the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input) then the chips appear below the input (where the user enters text) but still part of the component:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <input placeholder="New fruit..."
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">

  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
            [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

That might not get you exactly where you envisioned but I think it gets at the spirit of the solution you're looking for.

See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayqf52?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.html) I tweaked from the example.

Comment: Yes that i know!! I tried pulling it out.. then it stopped working. The error was ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

Comment: Try the link again. It worked for me. Although I think what @AjaySingh wants is to display it below the text field. Just like in Alexander's example.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with the link. It seems to work for me. I did not notice errors before. You have probably already tried this but if you order the input before `mat-chip-list` then the chips appear below the input (where the user enters text) but still part of the component. Would that suit your needs?

Comment: I have updated the StackBlitz to reflect that as well Ajay

Comment: Link is not working for me. I don't understand why it reloads the same page. Seems like a bug.

Comment: See this link. I am getting an <a href="#">https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-k-y9LEcdvHQ/W4hlPe1r_MI/AAAAAAAACN8/b9JzE9xMrxkjK60k4WBm5NnxrSFJtjMvwCLcBGAs/s0/Screen%2BShot%2B2018-08-31%2Bat%2B3.13.59%2BAM.png

Comment: Odd. I'm not sure what's going on since it works for me and Siddharth. I updated the answer with the reordered example in the meantime.

Comment: I have done this. It works fine but that is not my requirement. Seems like I have to write my own JS for this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Got it. Good luck! You should post your solution here when you figure it out.

Comment: Hey Ajay check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayqf52?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.html

Comment: this has helped tremendously; didn't know that all you need to make mat-form-field happy is to add the mat-chip-list then refer to it from some other part of the template. cannot +1 this enough. I +1'ed hard tho

Answer (score 2):

I used an input component that would take inputs and then add it to any array. Then I passed this array to chips component that would display chips.

> Template that calls keyDown and blur to add chips on these two events. Called another component that displays chips passing the array of chips.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Key Skills</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Skills" (keydown)="onAddSkills($event)" (blur)="onBlurMethod()" formControlName="keySkills" name="keySkills">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="chip-list">
        <chip-list [skills]="skills"></chip-list>
    </div>
</form>
```

> The component for this template

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

export interface Skills {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'key-skills',
  templateUrl: 'key-skills.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['key-skills.component.scss'],
})
export class KeySkillsComponent {
    skills: Skills[] = [];
    private form: FormGroup; 
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            "keySkills": new FormControl()
    });
    }

  onAddSkills(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key===",") {
        this.addSkillsToArray(this.form.value['keySkills']);
    }
  }

  onBlurMethod() {
            this.addSkillsToArray(this.form.value['keySkills'])
  }

  addSkillsToArray(skill) {
    if ((skill || '').trim()) {
        this.skills.push({name: skill.trim()});
            }
        this.form.reset();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

> Chip List template

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let skill of skills">
        {{skill.name}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

> and Component

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'chip-list',
  templateUrl: 'chip-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['chip-list.component.scss'],
})
export class ChipListComponent {
    @Input() skills;
}
```

> Easy peasy. The results of all this is: [image]

Comment: The result is this....https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-edLtQF-86xw/W4llGecq9NI/AAAAAAAACPI/RIAhqHoDNdkOVE4qTfIlzAdcUoSto9DcgCL0BGAYYCw/h122/Screen%2BShot%2B2018-08-31%2Bat%2B9.25.26%2BPM.png

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement that is playing with CSS position property.

But it's actually better to use flexbox: https://codepen.io/avreddy/pen/ppzraz

```
.md-chips { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
.md-chips md-chip{
  order: 2;
}
.md-chips .md-chip-input-container {
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you help with this version of angular material. https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

Comment: I think the question is on Angular and not on AngularJS. Your codepen has an AngularJS example. Are you sure this is doable with just CSS?

Comment: I don't think this would do. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It was solultion for Angular JS, right.

I was playing with Angular 2+ and tried to move input out of mat-chip-list on top of mat-form-field. It works for me.